# semodule -i fails with semodule: link.c:840: alias_copy_callback: Assertion `base_type->primary == target_type->s.value' failed

Tags: selinux

```
semodule -i zabbix_agentd.pp
```

fails with

```
semodule: link.c:840: alias_copy_callback: Assertion `base_type->primary == target_type->s.value' failed. 
Aborted (core dumped)
```

- Oracle Linux Server release 6.5
- policycoreutils.x86_64              2.0.83-30.1.0.2.el6_8

Content of the module is

```
module zabbix-agentd 1.0;

require {
        type zabbix_agent_t;
        class process setrlimit;
}

#============= zabbix_agent_t ==============
allow zabbix_agent_t self:process setrlimit;
```

Any clue on what is causing the error and how to fix will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [This CLOSED CANTFIX bugzilla report from RedHat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1258921) seems to match.